# Objective-C - fast enumeration on a subset of an array?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, collections, nsarray

Is there a simple way to do fast enumeration on a range of objects in an array? Something like...

```
for (Object *object in myArray startingAtIndex:50) {
    //do stuff
}
```

...to avoid having to do something like this...

```
for (Object *object in myArray) {
    NSUInteger index = [myArray indexOfObject:object];
    if (index >= 50) {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These come to my mind:

```
for (Object *object in [myArray subArrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(50, ([myArray count] - 49))]) {
    //do stuff
}
```

Which creates a temporary array though, thus potentially being slower (benchmark it!) than manual enumeration like this:

```
NSUInteger arrayCount = [myArray count];
for (NSUInteger i = 50; i < arrayCount; i++) {
    Object *object = [myArray objectAtIndex];
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Whichever is faster has to be determined by profiling. The `subArrayWithRange:` method might be faster.

Comment: You mean 'i < arrayCount' :-)

Answer (score 6):

If `myArray` is immutable, then `subArrayWithRange:` *probably* does not copying of pointers, though `retain` *probably* still has to be sent to everything in the subarray.

Overall, it really doesn't matter.  I've honestly never seen a case where fast enumeration vs. `indexOfObject:` was enough of a performance issue to warrant attention (there has always been something worse. :).

Another approach;  use `enumerateBlock:` and simply return from indices out of ranger (and use the stop flag).

```
[myArray enumerateWithBlock: ^(id o, NSUInteger i, BOOL *f) {
   if (i < 10) return;
   if (i > 20) { *f = YES; return; }
   ... process objects in range ...
}];
```

(You could even use the `options:` variant to enumerate concurrently.)

Comment: +1 - though I didn't use the solution, this is good advice too.